# Bottom sheets menu for mobile and popup menu for tablet

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to implement menu layout that I want to use inside Bottom Sheets layout for mobile and popup menu for tablets (the same like Google Drive app has, see screenshots). Does support library has components to implements this or there are some third-party libraries?

Or if there is no ready implementations I will be very appreciate for short description how to implement it in right way.

[image] [image]

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: @umni4ek Hello. nope

Comment: I added feature request https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37466271 and if it will be ignored I think one possible way to write own implementation of BottomSheetMENUDialogFragment using Navigation view class as a basis